# API twitter and twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to use the API Twitter with twitteR. I usually got from Twitter API 4 elements, specifically:

```
api_key<- "xxx"
api_secret <- "xxx"
access_token <- "xxx"
access_token_secret <- "xxx"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

I recently requested a new API from Twitter and I got only three key/token:

1. API key
2. API secret key
3. Bearer token

This is new for me. How I connect the API? I would prefer using twitteR library.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the user account access token and access token secret on the Twitter Developer Dashboard. On the Keys & Tokens page for your app, click the Generate button on the row that says "Access Token & Secret". Note that you *must* store these, along with your API key and API secret, in a password manager, as they will only be visible at generation time.

Sidenote: the twitteR library is very outdated and no longer maintained, we would strongly suggest moving over to a modern maintained alternative like rTweet.